# how to make checkbox unchecked when other checkbox is checked in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a table where it shows the list of deleted items.

User can either recover the item or delete permanently. i need help in making only one checkbox is checked in a table row and uncheck other checkbox when user try to check both. Also when checkbox is checked in table header, it should select all the checkboxes in that td.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.example').on('change', function() {
    $("tr").closest('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <table>
    <th>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />Recover</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />Delete</label>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a reason a jsfiddle link needs code here. Please respect the message you got when you tried to add the link

Comment: It sounds like you want to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes

Comment: This is *exactly* the scenario where you should be using `radio` inputs, not checkboxes. Then there is no JS code required at all.

Comment: Radio buttons are not working fine. it loops with ng-repeat and both checkboxes have different model. using radio is making one of them selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out myself without using radio buttons and its working fine.

JS code

```
    $scope.uncheckPermDelete = function (ip) {
 if($("input[name=perm_delete_check_"+ ip.id +"]").prop('checked', true)) {
        $("input[name=perm_delete_check_"+ ip.id +"]").prop('checked', false);
        ip.perm_delete = 0;
    }
};

$scope.uncheckRecover= function (ip) {
     if($("input[name=recover_check_"+ ip.id +"]").prop('checked', true)) {
        $("input[name=recover_check_"+ ip.id +"]").prop('checked', false);
        ip.deleted = 1;
    }
};
```

HTML code

```
<td ><input class="recover_check" name="recover_check_{{ip.id}}"  ng-change="uncheckPermDelete(ip)" type="checkbox" ng-model="ip.deleted" ng-true-value="0" ng-false-value="1" /></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is *exactly* the scenario where you should be using radio inputs, not checkboxes, as you get this behaviour by default without the need for any JS code. All you have to do is group the required `input` elements by their `name` attribute. Try this:

```html
<div ng-app>
  <table>
    <th>
      <label><input type="radio" name="foo1" />Recover</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label><input type="radio" name="foo1" />Delete</label>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="foo2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="foo2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="foo3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="foo3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are not working fine. it loops with ng-repeat and both checkboxes have different model. using radio is making one of them selected by default.